# There is vs there are in measurement units

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> There is 1.1 g NaCl in 1 mL
>
> There are 1.1 g NaCl in 1 mL

Which is right?

Comment: Is 1.1 grams plural? That's the question here.

Comment: You can dodge the issue with "1 mL of NaCl weighs 1.1 g".

Comment: What 'issue'? Decimals are plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are writing for publication, or academic purposes, consult the appropriate style guide. Here is what the [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers/faq0058.html#:~:text=Decimal%20quantities%20are%20considered%20to,one%20is%20singular%3A%201%20mile.) has to say:

> Decimal quantities are considered to be plural; quantities expressed
>   as fractions are considered to be singular. So write “0.8 miles” but
>   “eight tenths of a mile.” For decimal forms, only the number one is
>   singular: 1 mile. Once you add a decimal, even if it’s a zero, it
>   becomes plural: 1.0 miles.

Thus: there **are** 1.1 g[rams of] NaCl in 1 mL [of something].